# Scrapy pagination not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to learn Scrapy.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')

        for quote in quotes:
            text = quote.xpath(".//*[@class='text']/text()").extract_first()
            author = quote.xpath("//*[@itemprop='author']/text()").extract_first()
            tags = quote.xpath(".//*[@class='tag']/text()").extract();

            item = {
                'author_name':author,
                'text':text,
                'tags':tags
            }
            yield item
    next_page_url = response.xpath("//*[@class='next']/a/@href").extract_first()
    absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
    yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_next_page_url,callback=self.parse)
```

But scrapy is only parsing first page. What is wrong in this code. I copied it from youtube tutorial.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just that *all the requests except the first one are getting filtered as "offsite"*. This is because you have this extra `/` at the end of the `allowed_domains` value:

```
allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com/']
                    # REMOVE THIS SLASH^
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment out the allowed_domains. Optionally, remove the semicolon line # 15.
Moreover, indent the following code into the parse method:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath("//*[@class='next']/a/@href").extract_first()
absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_next_page_url,callback=self.parse)
```

so it will become this code:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    #allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')

        for quote in quotes:
            text = quote.xpath(".//*[@class='text']/text()").extract_first()
            author = quote.xpath("//*[@itemprop='author']/text()").extract_first()
            tags = quote.xpath(".//*[@class='tag']/text()").extract()

            item = {
                'author_name':author,
                'text':text,
                'tags':tags
            }
            yield item

        next_page_url = response.xpath("//*[@class='next']/a/@href").extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_next_page_url,callback=self.parse)
```